# Chained builder pattern in C++

Tags: c++, builder

I am trying to create a a chained builder in C++ as follows:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::string;
using std::vector;

class AbstractBuilder {
 protected:
    AbstractBuilder&
    add_field(string name, string value) {
        // blabla, add field to json structure
        return *this;
    }

};

class Event {
 public:
  class Builder : public AbstractBuilder {
   public:
    Builder& event(string event) {
      return add_field("event", event);
    }
    Builder& payload(string payload) {
      return add_field("payload", payload);
    }
  };
};

Event::Builder builder = Event::Builder().event("test");
```

The error I am getting is:

```
gcc test.cpp
test.cpp:22:14: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'Event::Builder' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'AbstractBuilder'
      return add_field("event", event);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:25:14: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'Event::Builder' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'AbstractBuilder'
      return add_field("payload", payload);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 errors generated.
```

I am a C++ noob, and don't quite understand the issue and how to resolve it. AFAIU the object returned from the add_field in the Event::Builder is going to be a reference to self, of type Event::Builder, not an abstract temp/rvalue. What am I missing? What might be a better way to achieve this (build a set of strong typed builders for some json structures). Any existing examples are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> AFAIU the object returned from the add_field in the Event::Builder is going to be [...]

You are applying higher level reasoning. What is the compiler allowed to assume? It sees that `add_field()` returns `AbstractBuilder&` and you are trying to return that (from `event()` and `payload()`) as a `Builder&`. How can this be done? In general, it cannot since not every `AbstractBuilder` is a `Builder`.

If you are absolutely certain that `add_field` will return `*this` (even after future modifications to the code), then you can explicitly tell the compiler to assume that the returned reference is a sub-object of a `Builder`.

```
return static_cast<Builder&>(add_field("event", event));
```

This is fragile though, since the compiler cannot detect if your assumption breaks (in the future). You might want to add a runtime assertion to detect breakage. Less fragile would be to force these functions to return `*this`:

```
add_field("event", event);
return *this;
```

This has its own drawback in that your code repeats itself. (If you ever change the semantics of what these functions return, you'll have multiple places to change.) There is a judgment call to be made as to which approach is preferable, or perhaps if the overall design should be rethought.